# Assign a value in Vue.js onchange of input

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I there guy's im struggling with a form that i need to complete using Vue.JS. Basically i need that the value of the field 'price_vat' its updated with some calculations evry time that input called 'price_user' is updated. Usign jquery evrything is going as well. Butt data is not passed to POST method using Vue.

```
<div class="col-md-6" v-show="form.active">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label >{{__('Price')}}</label>
                                <input type="number" v-model="form.price_user" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" v-show="form.active">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label >{{__('Price with VAT')}}</label>
                                <input type="number" v-model="form.price_vat" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: You should avoid using Jquery with Vue. In jQuery, you do things in an imperative way, but now you should think in a declarative way with Vue. Try to manipulate the DOM by using Vue directives.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly,, you want `form.price_vat` to change, every time you change `form.price_user` by typing inside the input.

you can do this using `watch`. just add the below your `methods` in vue:

```
watch:{
   'form.price_user':function():{
      this.form.price_vat += 1
    },
}
```

so in this code, you update the value of `form.price_vat` by 1 every time the `form.price_user` changes. you can do anything inside the function of `watch`.

the complete `vue` part will be :

```
data(){
  return:{
     form:{
       price_vat :'',
       price_user : '',
     }
  }
},

methods:{},

watch:{
       'form.price_user':function():{
          this.form.price_vat += 1
        },
}
```